# JSF 2.0 and spring-security 3 integration?

Tags: jsf, spring-security

Is it possible to combine that stuff? I just need a simple log-in page even without db backend :) Username/pwd should be stored in the securityContext...

Can somebody provide me a tutorial or show how the things must be configured?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

- The "plain HTML way". In this case you use a standard Spring Security configuration and use a standard HTML page, pointing the submit form to Spring Security login-url.
- The "JSF 2.0 way". What I do in this case is implement a backing bean for the login page and register an ActionListener for the submit button that dispatches to the login-url using FacesContext.getExternalContext(),dispatch(), and then calls FacesContext.responseComplete(), ending the request lifecycle. You might need to tweak your `web.xml` to allow Spring Security to intercept FORWARD requests for the login-url.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It looks pretty good too http://dmakariev.blogspot.com/2010/01/jsf-20-with-spring-3-and-spring.html I hope this will work...